# Does Google App Engine support Python's signal module?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, signals, sandbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you limit the allowed execution time of specific methods in the python version of Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859734/how-can-you-limit-the-allowed-execution-time-of-specific-methods-in-the-python-v)

When I run the following code in Eclipse, nothing happens, as expected:

```
import signal

def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    raise Exception, "Timed out!"
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal_handler)
```

However, when I try to run it using GAE, I get the error:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal_handler)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'signal'
```

My guess is that GAE is running a different installment of Python than Eclipse, that may have certain modules removed/blocked because google has that power.

I got the code from: [How to limit execution time of a function call in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366682/how-to-limit-execution-time-of-a-function-call-in-python)

Help? Thanks

Comment: `signal` is not on the list of [python customized modules](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#Pure_Python). It *could* be there is another module named `signal` in your project that is being imported instead of the stdlib `signal` module. Test the `signal.__file__` attribute to test.

Comment: Martijn Pieters: I had that thought, but I looked into it and python will not let a signal.py file supercede the builtin signal module.